# How to retrieve the value of the selected option from a dynamically created select in a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am dynamically creating a dropdown list in a table and want to retrieve the value of the selected item. I can get the value of other elements (e.g., input); however the dropdown has me stumped. In the below code the startDate is correct however parRating is always 1 (the first value in the select).

Note: I want the value (parIdArray) not the val (parRatingArray).

HTML for creating:

```
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><select name='parRating'>"
for (let i = 0; i <= paraArray; i++) {
    if (this.parRating  == parRatingArray[i]) {
        // set the current option to this.parRating 
        html += "<option selected name='parRatingOption' value='" + parIdArray[i] + "'>" + parRatingArray[i] + "</option>"
    }else {
        html += "<option name='parRatingOption' value='" + parIdArray[i] + "'>" + parRatingArray[i] + "</option>"
    }
};
html += "</select></td>";

if (this.patparStartDate == null) {
    html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' name='startDate' value=''></td>";
}else {
    html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><input type='date' name='startDate' value='" + this.patparStartDate + "'></td>";
}
```

HTML to retrieve values:

```
var parRating = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('option[name="parRatingOption"]').value;
alert("parRating: " + parRating);//always 1
var startDate = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[name="startDate"]').val();
```

Comment: I believe you need to target the selected option using `:selected` selector in jQuery - read more here: https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: Mate try this -> `var parRating = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('option[name="parRatingOption"]:selected').val();` - Let me know.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping This works. Please add as answer so I can accept. Kind regards, Glyn.

Comment: Posted an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to target the option selected in your code above using the jQuery [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

Also you need to use `.val()` to get the option value not the `value` attribute in jQuery

**Try this code below:**

```
var parRating = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('option[name="parRatingOption"]:selected').val();
```